# Creating a restricted wifi ap with static ip addresses

Tags: networking, wireless, raspberrypi, docker, netplan

What I am using:

- Raspberry Pi 4
- Ubuntu 21.04

What I need:

- Ethernet with dhcp to connect to my lan.
- A wifi ap that is isolated from the ethernet.
- The ability to assign static ip addresses to devices on the wifi network, since some may be unable to do some themselves.
- Have the ability for docker containers to access devices on the wifi ap, with any configuration done through docker-compose files.

Why:

- I would like any IoT devices to be be isolated from my network, but still accessable by homeassistant.

What I have done:

- Hours of googling, installing and uninstalling hostapd and dnsmasq. Editing config files in various way. A few times I got a network to show up but one time it would not assign ip addresses and the other it had access to the outside world.

I usually don't post on stack overflow but I am almost to the point of giving up.

Comment: AskUbuntu is a site with a format - one question per one thread. Please create separate threads for many questions.

Comment: This is one question?